# Как развернуть два Flask-приложения на одном сервере на одном поддомене?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose

Ребята, привет.

У меня есть два в принципе независимых друг от друга приложения на Flask. Каждое из них упаковано в свой  Docker (с помощью docker-compose). Но мне нужно, чтобы эти два приложения были на одном поддомене (можно, чтобы они были на разных портах или в разных поддиректориях типа sub.domain.com/1  и sub.domain.com/2). Как это сделать?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно запустить оба приложения на разных портах через Docker, а потом в настройках своего веб-сервера указать нужный путь с проксирированием HTTP-запросов на нужный порт приложения.

Comment: а как настроить веб-сервер и указать нужный путь с проксирированием HTTP-запросов на нужный порт приложения? Это в Nginx делается? Можете поделиться конфигом?

Comment: upstream + location + proxy_pass